# `long` and `double` are same when converting from `int ` by compiler

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading, ambiguous-call

I was studying function overloading in c++, and I saw an ambiguous condition, in the program,

```
long add(long a){
    long b = a;
    return b;
}

double add(double a){
    double b = a;
    return b;
}

int main(){
    int x;
    x = add(10);
    printf("x : %d", x);
    getch();
    return 0;   
}
```

The reason of ambiguity given in the book was, the compiler may convert `int` either in `long` or in `double`. So compiler generates an error. I run this and the result was same, **error**.

So how `long` and `double` are **equivalent**?
what's the actual reason of **ambiguity** here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that `long` and `double` are equivalent in themselves, but rather the *conversion rules* `int->long` and `int->double` have equivalent priority, so the compiler faces an ambiguity in the presence of both options.